# Python 3: Como recuperar a chave nomes depois de um sorted

Tags: python

Olá alguém pode me ajudar a recuperar valores dessa lista de dicionário?

```
sellers = [
            {"name": "Joaquina", "store": 2, "value": 1200.00},
            {"name": "Pedro", "store": 2, "value": 120.00},
            {"name": "Maria", "store": 1, "value": 450.00},
            {"name": "Fernanda", "store": 1, "value": 4000.00},
            {"name": "Patricia", "store": 1, "value": 100.00},

        ]
```

Quando eu faço essa operação no PythonTutor

```
def sales_goals(self, sellers):
        abaixo_da_meta = sorted([vendedor["value"] for vendedor in sellers if vendedor["value"] < 500])
        vendedores_falta_meta = [vendedor["name"] for vendedor in sellers if vendedor["value"] == abaixo_da_meta]
        return vendedores_falta_meta
```

A variavel vendedores_falta_meta não recupera os nomes da variavel abaixo_da_meta e sim uma lista vazia, obrigada!

Comment: Por que utilizou o `sorted`? Precisa dos valores classificados?

Comment: Sim preciso ele em ordem crescente nesse caso e há um outro caso muito parecido mas preciso de ordem descrecente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não precisa criar uma lista apenas com o valores de `value` para classificá-los em ordem crescente e depois obtê-los novamente. Você pode filtrar e classificar sempre mantendo o seu dicionário original e classificá-los utilizando o parâmetro `key`.

```py
from operator import itemgetter

sellers = [
  {"name": "Joaquina", "store": 2, "value": 1200.00},
  {"name": "Pedro", "store": 2, "value": 120.00},
  {"name": "Maria", "store": 1, "value": 450.00},
  {"name": "Fernanda", "store": 1, "value": 4000.00},
  {"name": "Patricia", "store": 1, "value": 100.00}
]

abaixo_da_meta = filter(lambda seller: seller['value'] < 500, sellers)
vendedores_falta_meta = sorted(abaixo_da_meta, key=itemgetter('value'))

print(vendedores_falta_meta)
```

A saída será:

```
[
  {'name': 'Patricia', 'store': 1, 'value': 100.0}, 
  {'name': 'Pedro', 'store': 2, 'value': 120.0}, 
  {'name': 'Maria', 'store': 1, 'value': 450.0}
]
```

Que são os vendedores abaixo da meta classificados em ordem crescente pelo valor de `value`.

Comment: muito bom, não sabia que dava para fazer assim

Comment: Anderson como faço para ter uma saída assim? [Patricia, Pedro, Maria]

Comment: @MargotPaonGarcia Pode fazer `vendedor['name'] for vendedor in vendedores_falta_meta`, ou `map(itemgetter('name'), vendedores_falta_meta)`

Comment: Obrigada pela dica!

Comment: eu faço um convite aqui pra explicar melhor o que é o itemgetter, e como poderia ser usado um lambda no lugar.

Answer (score 0):

abaixo_da_meta é uma lista, você tem que percorrer ela para conseguir comparar os valores corretamente.

```
sellers = [
            {"name": "Joaquina", "store": 2, "value": 1200.00},
            {"name": "Pedro", "store": 2, "value": 120.00},
            {"name": "Maria", "store": 1, "value": 450.00},
            {"name": "Fernanda", "store": 1, "value": 4000.00},
            {"name": "Patricia", "store": 1, "value": 100.00},

        ]

def sales_goals(sellers):
    abaixo_da_meta = sorted([vendedor["value"] for vendedor in sellers if vendedor["value"] < 500])
    vendedores_falta_meta = []
    for m in abaixo_da_meta:
        for vendedor in sellers:
            if(m == vendedor["value"]):
                vendedores_falta_meta.append(vendedor["name"])

    return vendedores_falta_meta
```

Comment: Oi Gabriel teu código dá essa saída ['Pedro', 'Maria', 'Patricia'] no PythonTutor e precisaria dessa aqui [Patricia, Pedro, Maria]

Comment: só inverter a ordem dos for

Comment: Desse jeito? ` for vendedor in sellers:
        for m in abaixo_da_meta:
            if(m == vendedor["value"]):
                vendedores_falta_meta.append(vendedor["name"]) `

Comment: eu já editei agora esta dando essa saída